# can I underline bold or change the color of HTTPS links in chat bot dialogue

Tags: community, chat, einstein-chatbot

My team is looking to begin utilizing chat bots to serve up knowledge articles to visitors of our webpage and we have noticed that any links that we set up with merge tags do not explicitly show that its a link.
[image]

To the user (until hovered upon) it looks like plain text. I have been looking for a way to alter this to make it either bold or underlined but have yet to find a solution. Has anyone found a way to alter this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003cG1QAI) that is raised and currently open, and to make the knowledge articles as a link, the only way I found was to have a custom lwc [implementation](https://techforceservices.com.au/how-to-make-einstein-bots-ui-recipe-using-lightning-web-component/).